# How to set re-focus after drop down list value changed?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have asp.net web app based on web forms.
A 'Drop Down List' has AutoPostBack property. My backend code is working well. But after changing the 'Drop-Down List' value, my page reloaded and start to show the top of the page.

I want to keep 'Drop Down List' item focused after selecting a value. How can I do that?
Here is my 'Drop Down List' control code.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPackagingMaterials" CssClass="form-control select2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPackagingMaterials_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Comment: Put your dropdownlist in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: what does your selectedindexChange method look like? be sure you set it there can double check that you aren't "resetting" anything in you page load event, be sure there is check on if(!Page.IsPostBack) so code does not run unintendedly on every post back but just on the first postback.As far as setting focus, just call dropdownlist.Focus();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
```